# Python os.environ.get not returning value

Tags: python

I am using below code to get environment variable in Azure Devops pippelines, using ubuntu latest vmimage.

```
os.environ.get("xyz")
```

But it's returning None value. When I print os.environ then I can see the xyz key and value, I am not sure what's happening wrong here.

"xyz" is added in the Azure pipeline by using Azure Variable Group.

Python (Linux) 3.8.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, May 11 2021, 07:01:05)

Please guide.
Thanks

Comment: where do you print `os.environ` from? the same script?

Comment: Yes, in same execution context, same script. os.environ gives values but os.environ.get("xyz") not.

Comment: Please provide a complete example. We have only your word that the exact name `xyz` is in the environment. How was the name added to the environment in the first place?

Comment: "xyz" is added in the Azure pipeline by using Azure Variable Group.

Comment: Does `os.getenv('xyz')` give the same result?

Comment: Also worth noting [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) behavior of `os.environ`: *"This mapping is captured the first time the os module is imported, typically during Python startup as part of processing `site.py`. Changes to the environment made after this time are not reflected in `os.environ`, except for changes made by modifying `os.environ` directly."*

Comment: Yes, os.getenv('xyz') also gives None

Comment: Both os.getenv('xyz') and os.environ are running one after another in the script, so there should not be any impact of site load mapping behavior.